# Setting background images in Jekyll stylesheets

Tags: css, background-image, jekyll

Given that I have the following markup on my Jekyll site:

```
<header>
  <hgroup>
    <h1>Page title</h1>
    <h2>Page subtitle</h2>
  </hgroup>
</header>
```

I'm trying to apply a background image it using CSS, however, I need to use the {{ site.baseurl }} variable so the location of the image file is parsed correctly. Unfortunately, the following code does not work:

```
header {
  background-image: url('{{ site.baseurl }}/img/bicycle.jpg');
}
```

Inline styles actually do work with {{ site.baseurl }} and the below code works.

```
<header style="background-image: url('{{ site.baseurl }}/img/bicycle.jpg');">
```

But I really don't want to use inline styles. What is the method to apply background images to Jekyll sites?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I managed to get it to work by setting the url in my `_config.yml`file like so:

```
# Site settings
url: "http://www.SITE_DOMAIN.com"
```

The background image property now works when set to:

```
background-image: url('/images/IMAGE_NAME.jpg')
```

Answer (score 4):

In your CSS file, add an empty YAML block to the file, and Jekyll will render it.

CSS file :

```
---
---

header {
  background-image: url('{{ site.baseurl }}/img/bicycle.jpg');
}
```

Comment: This works fine when I add it to my CSS file. However, because I'm using SASS, the dashes don't compile right. Does this mean I have to manually add the dashes after the SASS compiles? Is there any way to get this to work with SASS?

Comment: maybe you could set a variable in your config.rb and have that compile with the YAML block?